# How to convert object to specific class with using type information

Tags: c#, .net

I have a interface. That interface name is IQueue. Also I have concrete classes. Their names are MyMessage1 and MyMessage2.

```
public interface IQueue 
{
}

public class MyMessage1 : IQueue 
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
}

public class MyMessage2 : IQueue 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting all the concrete classes implemented from `IQueue` with reflection and create a instance.

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => typeof(IQueue).IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass)
    .ToList);

foreach(var type in types) 
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

Instance is an object. How I can cast to specific class without using below code? Is it possible.

```
(MyMessage1)Activator.CreateInstance(type)
(MyMessage2)Activator.CreateInstance(type)
```

I want to create a specific class instance using type information

Comment: if you already know the concrete type - why not simply `new MyMessage1()`?

Comment: The exact type is only known at runtime so you can never know the exact type at compile time. So you will always need to check the type after creation if you need to know the exact type.

Answer (score -1):

Cast to the type `IQueue` since all the types you want to instantiate implement that interface.

```
IQueue instance = (IQueue)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Add methods and properties you want to use to that interface. The concrete classes will then have to implement these methods and properties and you can access them via the interface.